# Cucumber tests shows passed but protractor doesn't interact with web elements

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am new to Protractor+Cucumber+Typescript and created a sample framework using Page Object Design and small script to perform some click actions.
URL: http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/login

I am trying to click on "Customer Login" button but it does not interact with the element and cucumber still shows test passed.

I tried with async/await to handle promises but no luck.
Protractor Version: 5.4.2
TypeScript Version: 3.3.4000
Node Version: v10.15.3
NPM version: 6.4.1

```
Feature File:
Feature: To login into XYZ bank

@OutlineScenario
Scenario: Login as Customer

Given I am on XYZ Bank home page
Then I click Customer Login
Then I select Name of Customer
Then I click Login
```

Page Object:

```
    import { element, by } from "protractor";
    import { Select } from "../utilities/selectClass";
  export class loginPage {

        //elements

        customerLoginButton = element(by.cssContainingText('.btn btn-primary btn-lg', 'Customer Login'));
        loginButton = element(by.className('btn btn-default'));
        yourNameDropDown = element(by.model('custId'));
        bankManagerLoginButton = element(by.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Bank Manager Login')]"));
        homeButton = element(by.className('btn home'));

        //function to click on Customer Login
        customerLogin() {
            this.customerLoginButton.click();
        }

        //function to select on Name from Dropdown
        selectName() {
            const select: Select = new Select(this.yourNameDropDown);
            select.selectByVisibleText("Harry Potter");
        }

        //function to click on Login
        clickLogin() {
            this.loginButton.click();
        }

        //function to click on Bank Manager Login
        bankManagerLogin() {
            this.bankManagerLoginButton.click();
        }

        clickHome() {
            this.homeButton.click();
        }
    }
```

StepDefinition:

```
import {loginPage} from "../pages/loginPage";
import {addCustomer} from "../pages/addCustomer";
import { browser } from "protractor";
import { Then, Given } from "cucumber";
const chai = require("chai").use(require("chai-as-promised"));
const expect = chai.expect;
const login: loginPage = new loginPage();
const addcustomer: addCustomer = new addCustomer();

Given('I am on XYZ Bank home page', function() {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal("Protractor practice website - Banking App");
   });

Then(/^I click Customer Login$/, function() {
   login.customerLogin();
  });

  Then('I select Name of Customer', function() {
   login.selectName();
 });

 Then('I click Login', function () {
   login.clickLogin();
 });
```

config.ts

```
import { browser, Config } from "protractor";
import { Reporter } from "../utilities/reporter";
const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";

export const config: Config = {
    seleniumAddress: "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub",

    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

    baseUrl: "http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/banking/#/login",

    capabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
    },

    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

    specs: [
        "../../features/*.feature",
    ],

    onPrepare: () => {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
    },

    cucumberOpts: {
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
        format: "json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json",
        require: ["../../typeScript/stepdefinitions/*.js", "../../typeScript/utilities/*.js"],
        strict: true,
        tags: "@CucumberScenario or @ProtractorScenario or @TypeScriptScenario or @OutlineScenario",
    },

    onComplete: () => {
        Reporter.createHTMLReport();
    },
}
```

Comment: Please share your protractor conf.js

Comment: added config.ts file

Comment: you turn off `Control Flow` in conf.js via `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,`, please read this page: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/async-await.md , then decide to use `Control Flow` or `async/await`.  No matter you choose which one,  each function in `StepDefinition` should return a promise-like object,  thus you should add `return` for each function in `StepDefinition`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webdriver's Control Flow (i.e. NOT async/await), you have to [return the last line of every step](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md), including `expects` that use `eventually`.  For example, `login.customerLogin()` is returning a promise that never gets resolved, you have to use `return login.customerLogin()` so Cucumber can resolve it for you.

FWIW, we've found that switching to `async/await` instead of control flow has taken a lot of the pain out of writing tests in protractor.  I can't count how many times we've forgot to return a single step or a single assertion and has false positives or weird errors.

Comment: could you please elaborate with some examples, how to use with/without async/wait.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor runs its functions asynchronously, so you have to wait until the promises are resolved. You can do it by using the `then` function, [here's](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) a guide on promises.

There is another way of handling promises by using `async/await` which I would recomment because your code is much more readable. You have to make all your step definition functions `async` and call the protractor functions with `await`, which will stop execution of the following code until the promise is resolved.
Your `customer login` function and step should then look like this:

```
async customerLogin() {
    await this.customerLoginButton.click();
}

Then(/^I click Customer Login$/, async function() {
    await login.customerLogin();
}
```

If you are using `asnyc/await` you don't need to use `chai-as-promised`, because using `await` on an `async` function returns the value just like `chai`'s `eventually` which waits for a promise to resolve.
So you have to replace your current `I am on XYZ Bank home page` step with the following:

```
expect(await browser.getTitle()).to.equal("Title");
```

Here are some great sources:

- [How to use async/await in protractor](https://medium.com/@anandujjwal/end-to-end-testing-using-protractor-with-async-await-46dc11d948d0)
- [How to use page object model with async/await](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md#with-page-objects)